# How Do you access function props in your class component?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to set up react redux, also i have set it but I am getting an error **TypeError: _this.props.showLoader is not a function. (In '_this.props.showLoader(true)', '_this.props.showLoader' is undefined)**.

> this.props.showLoader(true)

This function has been defined in Action.js file you can find it below.

This error comes whenever I try to call a function from Root.js file, you can find it below.

Below is the code what I have done so far:->

I have App.js file in which I have set for provider and store

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/redux/Store'
import Root from './src/root/Root'



function App() {
  return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={localStyles.container}>
          <Root/>
        </View>
        </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;

const localStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

This is the Navigation Route File

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TutorialSwipeScreen from '../components/viewcontrollers/onboarding/TutorialSwipeScreen'


 const Stack = createStackNavigator();

 function goStack() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login Screen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }


 export default goStack;
```

My Root.js file
where I am trying to this.props.showLoader it gives me error

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native'
import NavigationRoute from './NavigationRoutes'

import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

class Root extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       console.warn('props=', this.props)
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.call()
   }

   call = () => { 
       this.props.showLoader(true)
       
   }

   render () {
       return (
           <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
               <NavigationRoute/>
           </View>
       )
   }

}

export default Root;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   rootContainer: {
     flex: 1,
   }
 });
```

My RootContainer.js File

```
 import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'

 import * as Actions from '../redux/Actions'

 import Root from './Root'

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
        shouldShowLoader: state.dataReducer._showLoader,
        shouldChangeCounting: state.dataReducer.counter
     }
 }

 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     const mergedActions = Object.assign({}, Actions);
     return bindActionCreators(mergedActions, dispatch)
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root);
```

My Store.js file

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'

import reducers from './RootReducer'

export default createStore(reducers);
```

My RootReducer.js

```
 import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
 import dataReducer from './reducers/Reducer'

 const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
     dataReducer,
 })

 export default rootReducer;
```

My Action.js file which has a function showLoader(bool) which I try to call from Root.js which gives me an error as I have quoted above.

```
export const DISPLAY_LOADER = 'DISPLAY_LOADER';
export const REFRESH = 'REFRESH';
export const COUNTER = 'COUNTER';

 export function showLoader(bool) {
    return {
      type: DISPLAY_LOADER, data: bool,
    };
  }

  export function refresh() {
    return {
      type: REFRESH, data: true,
    };
  }

  export function counting(count) {
      return {
          type: COUNTER, data: count
      }
  }
```

And Finally Reducer.js file code goes here

```
import { DISPLAY_LOADER, REFRESH, WELCOME_POPUP, LOGIN_RELOAD, MESSAGE_POPUP, LOGOUT, COUNTER} from '../Actions';

 const initialState = {
     counter: 5,
     _showLoader: false,
     _showMessagePopup: false,
     _loginReload: false,
     _refresh: false,
     _heading: 'Message Heading',
     _message: 'PWG Custom Message',
 }


 const dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case DISPLAY_LOADER: {
            return {...initialState, _showLoader: action.data}
        }
        case REFRESH: {
            return {...initialState, _refresh: action.data}
        }
        case LOGOUT: {
            return {...initialState, _refresh: true}
        }
        case COUNTER: {
            return {...initialState, counter: action.data}
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }

 }

 export default dataReducer;
```

So where my mistake is I am not able to find with what lines of code I am receiving error at my end. Please help. Also I am new to react native please bear with me.

Thanks

Comment: what can i see for now is your reducer is faulty, as it give back `initialState` not `state` after each reducing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer, I am answering my own post.

In the App.js File You need to import

> RootContainer

instead of

> Root

That’s it and it works Voila.

```
import RootContainer from './src/root/RootContainer'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `showLoader` tied to your redux reducer.

what i can suggest you, you should return `state` not `initialState` in your reducer. Basically what youre doing is after each change of state in redux, everything else will go back to its `initialState` but not the changed state itself.

You also didn't pass props `showLoader` to your `Root` component. If your intention is using `showLoader` as a setState function for your `Root` component, you should define the function in your `mapDispatchToProps` in your `connect` function

Comment: The First Option of returning state doesn’t works for me. As I returned ```case DISPLAY_LOADER: { const newState = Object.assign({}, state, { _showLoader: action.data }); return newState; } 
```
Now the second options I don’t get yours point How should I pass props can you please elaborate more. And yes I want to use it as a setState, but how will you define is it by importing to the rootContainer class is that so ??

Comment: what you do is instead of `{...initialState}` you do `{...state}`

Comment: No returning {...state} throws error. I want to modify _showLoader state so all state will be initial and only _showLoader state will change

Comment: what if instead doing `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     const mergedActions = Object.assign({}, Actions);
     return bindActionCreators(mergedActions, dispatch)
 }`

you just pass your actions to `connect` function like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, {/** your actions here */})(Root);`

Comment: I have passed all the actions by merging it by bindActionCreators. But I wrote it as you said  ```export default connect(mapStateToProps, {showLoader: () => dispatch({ type: 'DISPLAY_LOADER' })})(Root);```  I Did this way, but still it gives me the error the same error

Comment: no you do it by `connect(mapStateToProps, { showLoader })(Root);` the `showLoader` you defined in `redux/Actions`, just pass it there and any function you need to pass

Comment: Yes I wrote this way  ```export default connect(mapStateToProps, {showLoader})(Root);```   but still i am getting the same error

Comment: the error reads  **TypeError: _this.props.showLoader is not a function. (In '_this.props.showLoader(true)', '_this.props.showLoader' is undefined)**

Comment: Did You tested at your end ? does it works at your end, unfortunately it doesn’t works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226501/discussion-between-manish-and-hadi-kar).

Comment: Hi Hadi KAR, it worked changing the Root to RootContainer.